# How to make a face using Constraint Layout?

Tags: android, layout, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to make an app in Android Studio for constructing identikits.
I have a constraint layout with ImageViews of every face part, but when I loads they all shuffle. I found out that the ImageViews don't scale with the layout itself, and that's exactly what will fix my problem.

[when the face parts should be bigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBMh0.png)
[when the face parts should be smaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vheIi.png)

I think the key is in these attributes:
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

both "wrap_content" and "40dp" are rigid. I would like they to be otherwise